# Devel::Cover usage with a wrapper and a .pm module with a test script

Tags: perl, code-coverage, devel-cover

I have a .pm module (`Main.pm`) which has a wrapper around it written in perl(Mainwrapper). These two are part of development team. I have written a test script in perl to test the wrapper(`Testwrapper.pl`). Now, I need to get the coverage using [`Devel::Cover`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aCover) for the wrapper(written by someone else) and its test script(written by me). The Mainwrapper of course uses the .pm module.

I tried using `perl -MDEVEL:COVER Testwrapper.pl` after having all Mainwrapper `Main.pm` and `Testwrapper.pl` in the same directory. Also included `Main.pm` in the `Testwrapper.pl` code. I could only get coverage for `Testwrapper.pl` and the `Main.pm` module in the report. One workaround I performed was to rename the Mainwrapper as `Mainwrapper.pm` and included in the `Testwrapper.pl` file. This would give me coverage for all. However, this is not a long term solution. Can anyone please tell me how to go with this?

Comment: Welcome back to SO.  I understand you're having trouble, but I think you could do a lot to make your question and situation more clear.  Perhaps creating a list of the files involved and their descriptions instead of embedding everything into a paragraph?  I think you have a [`good question`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it just needs some work to make it more likely that you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about the different modules and scripts. But I gather that you have a module Main.pm, two wrapper modules using Main.pm, and two scripts using the two wrapper modules.

By running `perl -MDevel::Cover script1.pl` and `perl -MDevel::Cover script2.pl` you create two directories in *cover_db/runs*. Then you can run the command *cover*. This will generate the file cover_db/coverage.html. Open the HTML file in a browser and you should see a merged report containing script1.pl and script2.pl.

Comment: Hey Barney, Thanks for replying. I have one main.pm , one wrapper called as mainwrapper(this is not a module and still need to find its coverage) and one testscript. My script tests certain functionality for the wrapper. How do I test the code coverage for the wrapper with my script.

Comment: Thus, there one perl script(test script) tests the wrapper and the wrapper uses the .pm module. I need a way to find the code coverage for wrapper with my test script without converting the wrapper into a package. Please advise!

Comment: You are on the right way. First make sure that you can run your script. Then collect coverage info by running your script with _perl -MDevel::Cover_ . Then generate a HTML report with the command _cover_. Then view the report. If your module or script is not included in the report then it is simply not covered.

Comment: I can only find the coverage for the wrapper by making it as a package and using it in my testscript. I am looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: I gather that be wrapper you mean a script that is called on the commandline and uses Main.pm. Previously I was ithingin about a module that provides a simplified interface to a module. For your case I see two possibilities.

Comment: I gather that be wrapper you mean a script that is called on the commandline and uses Main.pm. Previously I was thinking about a module that provides a simplified interface to another module. For your case I see different possibilities. First you can move code from your wrapper to a sub in the main omodule and call that sub from your testscript. Or you can call your wrapper in the testscript. E.g. system( "perl -MDevel::Cover mainwrapper" ) and then view the merged report. Or call _perl -MDevel::Cover mainwrapper_ directly.

Comment: So, choice no. 1 is not something that can be used. I cannot and not supposed to modify the wrapper. So, when I call perl -MDevel::Cover mainwrapper will that give me a code coverage for my testscript for the wrapper. I thought this would give me code coverage for wrapper wrt the .pm module(which is not useful for my testing). I ned to know how much code is being covered for the wrapper in my testscript. Plz advise.